# How javascript alert a css value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there I'm having a problem. I made a box of blue color in HTML/CSS and want javascript to alert the name of color when the box is clicked. Here is my code.`

```js
var clr = document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor;
document.getElementById("box").onclick= function() {
    alert(clr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <style>
     #box {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
     }

  </style>
   </head>

   <body>
  <div id="box" class="box">
  </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you want alert particular property or full css details

Comment: ..... aaaaand...? What is the status of your problem? What happens?

Comment: The `background-color` is set via CSS and not inline styles, so you should use `getComputedStyle`

Comment: _alert the name of color_....i guess this closes the question itself.

Comment: With getcomputed my guess is het will get the RGB values, not the actual name ...

Comment: Valid point @Yoeri but I don't think there is an alternate unless he sets the background via inline styles.

Comment: Only a particular property #raja maha

Comment: Lemme try it harry

Comment: `var clr = document.getElementById("box");`

`document.getElementById("box").onclick= function() {`
    `alert(window.getComputedStyle(clr,null).getPropertyValue("background-color"));`
`}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getComputedStyle()`. `.style` is use to set a new value for target element.

```js
var div     = document.getElementById("box"), // element
    divCSS  = window.getComputedStyle(div), // element CSS 
    bgColor = divCSS.getPropertyValue('background-color'); // property


document.getElementById("box").onclick= function() {
    alert(bgColor);
}
```

```css
#box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, i guessed right , you'll still need some JS to convert the RGB values to a named color

Comment: @Yoeri, you're right, but that would require a sort of library, or at last creating a array with values for each for all registered color names.

Comment: Indeed, best answer ... no can do without additional translation code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <style>
     #box {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
     }

  </style>
   </head>

   <body>
  <div id="box" class="box">
  </div>
   </body>

</html>
<script>
/*  var clr = document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor;*/
    document.getElementById("box").onclick= function() {

    var ele = document.getElementById("box");
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
    var bColor = style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
    alert(bColor);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Ok. It gives the rgb value. Any way to get the name of colour like blue, actually I'm trying to make a color game in which user will told to click on given color and user will click on the box and programme will check whether it is the same color that was told to him.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the variable clr inside the function.
Also invoke the fucntion using onclick on the div itself.
Using regex to get the property backgorund color in whole css.
You can also use filter on #box using

```
var boxCss = clr.match(/#box{((.*\s*.*)*)}/g);


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>

            </title>
    <script>

     function colorAlert() {
           var clr = document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].innerHTML;   
    var res = clr.match(/background-color:.*;/g);
    alert(res[0]);
    }
    </script>
                <style>
                #box{

                            height: 100px;
                            width: 100px;
                            background-color: blue;
                            margin: 0px;
                            display: inline-block;
                    }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="box" class="box" onclick="colorAlert();">

                    </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: so this alerts blue right??? if not then remove the answer.

Comment: No, this helps me get comments of people who don't try but criticize.

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
var clr = document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor;
document.getElementById("box").onclick= function() {
    alert(clr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="box" class="box" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;background-color: blue;margin: 0px;display: inline-block;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can also use below code with provided html

```
  <script>
    var clr=  window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("box")).getPropertyValue('background-color'); // property
   document.getElementById("box").onclick= function() {
   alert(clr);
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have two ways to solve this :

1. keep `<script>` tag after after closing `<div>` tag
2. move `clr` var in side the `onclick function`,then you can write `<script>` tag where ever you want

Comment: did you understand the requirement?